# Can't extract generic part from the function arguments in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

There is the basic example:

```
interface BasicProperties {
    a: number,
    b: number,
    c: number
}

interface Properties extends BasicProperties {
    d: number
}

function generic<T extends BasicProperties>(args: Omit<T, keyof BasicProperties> & Partial<BasicProperties>): T {
    const {
        a,
        b,
        c,
        ...other
    } = args

    const properties: Omit<T, keyof BasicProperties>= other;

    // The properties is the temporary value. It passed to a complicated function that returns the fully defined T
    // Just example:
    return {
        a: a || 0,
        b: b || 0,
        c: c || 0,
        ...properties,
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM7AQBSgewAdoxgINkBvAKGTuTgC5kQBXAWwCNoAaW+zszZde-OgiEduUagF9q1UJFiIUeIiTIUIAD0ggAJhXRZcBYlFLkqY5AckiZ86jFYgEpfCGQBzCCGhsAB4AFWRdfSM0TGx1CysMAD4ACjgoHwxmAHl2YDBQnmQAawgAT3wYaNM4zXJE5AAyZBw00jgAGyCTWPNapIBKZjCaemQELwwwG1HRuD4ZgXmFsaWFgDoN-DAAC2hbWWQAXgZ0jAVR8ZBJ5EJeyy1s3PyQwpLyyu6zDXu6463dqAAbnO9AA9KDkCFdjc7glkMAKDsUJB2IR8FA0qVkAA3DqsCBrZAASSmhEwGAgBmQYHwDDG+FR7WwcEgVNc7k83h2LOQUAgYFYUCu1Ohrna7SxBggMFAlMhtnByAAUqxrro4IyIIxbHyBULpssmHSAD7G5AABlWM0EyE4yFNFqtF2YCHtZsttlGGzWt2+CSt8lkQA).

It leads to the following error:

> Type 'Omit<Omit<T, keyof BasicProperties> & Partial, "a" | "b" | "c">' is not assignable to type 'Omit<T, keyof BasicProperties>'.
> Type 'Exclude<keyof T, keyof BasicProperties>' is not assignable to type 'Exclude<Exclude<keyof T, keyof BasicProperties>, "a" | "b" | "c">'.
> Type 'keyof T' is not assignable to type 'Exclude<Exclude<keyof T, keyof BasicProperties>, "a" | "b" | "c">'.
> Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'Exclude<Exclude<keyof T, keyof BasicProperties>, "a" | "b" | "c">'.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Exclude<Exclude<keyof T, keyof BasicProperties>, "a" | "b" | "c">'.
> Type 'keyof T' is not assignable to type 'Exclude<keyof T, keyof BasicProperties>'.

What's wrong with `properties` type?

Comment: Does this help you?: https://tsplay.dev/WvElMm

Comment: I've updated the question to make my problem more clear. I'm sorry, that the previous example was not elaborated.

Comment: What does the `Properties` interface have to do with anything? What is the perceived advantage to `Omit<T, keyof BasicProperties> & Partial<BasicProperties>` compared to just `T extends Partial<BasicProperties>`? The compiler won't be able to infer `T` from a call to `generic()` with your version; can you show how you intend to call it? If you change the above to [this simpler version with more straightforward typings](https://tsplay.dev/WzOMEw) instead, what specifically breaks for you?

Comment: The point is that T shouldn't have undefined properties of `BasicProperties`. But the argument of generic function shouldn't require that properties.